# Electric Field as Negative Gradient of Potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, vector-fields

I am currently reading Griffith's Intro to Electrodynamics and I was confused about how he relates the electric field as the negative gradient of the potential.

Using the fact that electric fields are conservative, or equivalently that their line integrals are path-independent, we can well-define the potential difference:

$$
V(b) - V(a) := -\int_{a}^{b}\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}
$$

and by placing a reference point at infinity and defining $V$ there to be $0$, we can further define

$$
V(\vec{r}) := -\int_{\infty}^{\vec{r}} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}
$$

However, based on just this definition, we do not know any particular qualities about $V$, i.e. whether it is differentiable, or even continuous. Yet, he goes on to use the fundamental theorem of gradients and say that

$$
V(b)-V(a) = \int_{a}^{b}\nabla 
V \cdot d\vec{s}
$$

and hence since the first and third lines hold for any $a, b$, we must have that $\nabla V = -\vec{E}$. However, it is not apparent to me that $\nabla V$ may even exist since we do not know anything about the differentiability of $V$ just from our definition of it. What am I missing? The fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals requires the vector field to be continuous within some space containing the paths considered, which is a more strict requirement than shown here.

Comment: If you assume $E$ is continuous on a connected open set, then $V$ will be $C^1$ on that set. This is a simple exercise in analysis; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3967655/568204) for some details. For some fields, like the Coulomb field of a point charge, this continuity is obviously not satisfied at the location of the charge, so the theorem doesn't apply here (as expected).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for the link. It reaffirms what I learned from calculus that if a vector field $\vec{F}$ is continuous in a connected open set, then path-independency of line integrals of $\vec{F}$ is equivalent to $\vec{F}$ being conservative is equivalent to $\vec{F}$ being a gradient field (and hence the potential function must be $C^1$). But my main concern is why we should assume $\vec{F}$ or in this case $\vec{E}$ is continuous at all? Is there any reason a priori why electric fields are always continuous?

Comment: well, the electric field for a point charge is continuous away from the location of a point charge. So, any finite collection of point charges has continuous electric field on the complement of where the charges are located, and 'hence' for 'any' charge distrbution (line charge, surface charge, volume charge) the field is continuous away from the location of the charge (again, formulating this precisely is an exercise in analysis, particularly continuity of functions defined by integrals).